# Importing psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I am trying to import pscycopg2. I come across the rolling error while running `import psycopg2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module> from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
  ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so,' 2): Symbol not found: _lo_lseek64
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

I am stuck at it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `psycopg2` was compiled against a newer PostgreSQL `libpq` than the one that your OS X system is loading at runtime. You probably have multiple versions of PostgreSQL installed.

Check your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and make sure the newest PostgreSQL `libpq.5.dylib` is first on the path.